# How to update user profiles of 2 classes inheriting one same class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, inheritance, asp.net-core-identity

`ApplicationUser` inherits from `IdentityUser` class of ASP.NET Core Identity with some build-in properties.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
      [StringLength(450)]
      public string? Address { get; set; }
}
```

`Employee` class inherits from `ApplicationUser`.

```
public class Employee : ApplicationUser
{
      [Required]
      [StringLength(450)]
      public string? DepartmentId { get; set; }

      [ForeignKey("DepartmentId")]
      [InverseProperty("Employees")]
      public virtual Department? Department { get; set; }
}
```

`Applicant` class also inherits from `ApplicationUser` class:

```
public class Applicant : ApplicationUser
{
      [DataType(DataType.Date)]
      public DateOnly? Birthday { get; set; }

      [Display(Name = "Experience Years")]
      public int? ExperienceYears { get; set; }
}
```

This is `LoadAsync` method in the Razor page to load user profile based on role:

```
private async Task LoadAsync(ApplicationUser user)
{
    var userName = await _userManager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
    var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);
    var address = user.Address;

    Username = userName;

    Input = new InputModel
    {
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber,
        Address = address
    };
}
```

Here is the `OnPostAsync` method to update a profile:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
    }

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await LoadAsync(user);
        return Page();
    }

    user.Address = Input.Address;

    await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

    var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);

    if (Input.PhoneNumber != phoneNumber)
    {
        var setPhoneResult = await _userManager.SetPhoneNumberAsync(user, Input.PhoneNumber);

        if (!setPhoneResult.Succeeded)
        {
            StatusMessage = "Unexpected error when trying to set phone number.";
            return RedirectToPage();
        }
    }

    await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
    StatusMessage = "Your profile has been updated";

    return RedirectToPage();
}
```

How can I load existing properties value of `Employee` or `Applicant`?
How can I update their existing properties?

I've tried to use this code, but it doesn't update user properties.

```
if (user is Applicant applicant)
{
    applicant.Birthday = Input.Birthday;
    applicant.ExperienceYears = Input.ExperienceYears;
}
```

My program always create a new ApplicationUser instance by following method, so preceding if block always return null. I know that it's because this method use ApplicationUser as type. But It might be origin of the problem when retrieved user from database by `_userManager.GetUserAsync(User);` does only contain properties of ApplicationUser.

```
private ApplicationUser CreateUser()
    {
        try
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance<ApplicationUser>();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Can't create an instance of '{nameof(ApplicationUser)}'. " +
                $"Ensure that '{nameof(ApplicationUser)}' is not an abstract class and has a parameterless constructor, or alternatively " +
                $"override the register page in /Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml");
        }
    }
```

#### Update

My DbContext design here

```
public partial class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{ 
      public AppIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppIdentityDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
      {
      }
// I do not use `public virtual DbSet` for ApplicationUser, Applicant or Employee
// some other table's configurations here
}


protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>();
};
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea - OOP inheritance is not a good tool here - is it still possible for you to update your application's design?

Comment: I think I'm stuck designing database with 2 type of user inherit from based class ApplicationUser with common properties. I've update database design in question section. Anyone has better solutions?

Comment: Could you provide the source code, maybe a github repo?
Are both types mapped to the same table with a `discriminator` column?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be more effective to create a single 'user' and assign roles to that user instead of creating two different user classes?
You can easily switch to a role-based structure.

Firstly, create a class named ApplicationRole that extends from IdentityRole:

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    [InverseProperty("Role")]
    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Then update ApplicationUser as follows:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [StringLength(450)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

And you just need to make this change in AppIdentityDbContext, you don't need to add DbSet for ApplicationUser and ApplicationRole, they are already in IdentityDbContext.

```
public partial class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>
//In order: Custom user class, custom role class and primary key type
```

**Note:** When using this structure, as Identity Framework automatically establishes a many-to-many relationship, it's advisable not to interact with it through UserManager. Instead, operations should be performed via the EF Core DbContext. Otherwise, direct access like ApplicationUser.Role might not be accessible.